# JS Regex to remove numbers after last hyphen in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to remove numbers after the last hyphen. I tried the below but not working.

```
const str = 'HYC-HTY-VB23';
const result = str.toLowerCase().replace(/-\d*$/, "");
console.log('result = ', result);
```

If I change it to \w it removes all the values after the last - hyphen but I only want the numbers after the last hyphen to be removed. Anyone have any ideas around this in regex.

Thanks,

Comment: So what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for every possible way

`HYC-HTY-VB23  ->  hyc-hty-vb` ✓ 
`HYC-HTY-23VB  ->  hyc-hty-vb` ✓ 
`HYC-HTY-2V3B  ->  hyc-hty-vb` ✓ 
`HYC-HTY-2VB3  ->  hyc-hty-vb` ✓

```js
const str = 'HYC-HTY-2V3B'; // Even for this
const result = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^-]+$/, (textAfterHypen) => {
  const withoutNumber = textAfterHypen.replace(/\d/g, "");
  return withoutNumber;
});
console.log('result =', result);
```

#### One liner

```js
const str = 'HYC-HTY-2V3B';
const result = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^-]+$/, t => t.replace(/\d/g, ""));
console.log('result =', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the leading characters that come after the hyphen but before the end of the string, then replace with those characters:

```js
const str = 'HYC-HTY-VB23';
const result = str.toLowerCase().replace(/(-.*?)\d*$/, "$1");
console.log('result = ', result);
```

If there won't be any numbers in the leading section, only letters (eg, ending in `-12VB23` isn't a possibility) then `(-[a-z]*)\d*$` would work.

The hyphen logic might not be necessary either - unless you *only* want to remove digits from inputs with hyphens (and leave other inputs that end in digits alone), you could `.replace(/\d+$/, '')`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a single replacement matching 1 or more digits asserting any char except a `-` at the right until the end of the string using a positive lookahead `(?=[^-]*$)`

```
\d+(?=[^-]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/22DJYF/1)

```js
const str = 'HYC-HTY-VB23';
const result = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\d+(?=[^-]*$)/, "");
console.log('result = ', result);
```

---

If there has to be a hyphen present, you could also use

```
(?<=-[^-]*)\d+(?=[^-]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h0DxFk/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
const str = 'HYC-HTY-VB23';
const result = str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?<=-[^-]*)\d(?=[^-]*$)/g, "");
console.log('result =', result);
```

**Results**: `result = hyc-hty-vb`

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^-]*                    any character except: '-' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^-]*                    any character except: '-' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```